Where are the animated frame icons for the News & Interests widget stored, and what are reliable ways to locate the URLs associated with them
I am currently using Windows 10 and Everything by VoidTools. Sometimes Windows animates the icon used in the News & Interests widget. These frames show up when searching in the correct directory, and they are named with a specific name scheme, example: W01_Sunny, W meaning Weather, 01 being the first frame, which goes all the way up to 40 for forty frames.
When I change the location I set my weather forecast to in the widget, the frames for a new weather type from that location shows up. Sometimes, if an a weather alert icon animated previously before changing the location, and after changing the location has a weather alert, the frames for that alert animation show up too, being listed under WA_ instead of W_. The same goes for animations for sunset, and temperatures, being listed under WI_. I can keep changing the location to load these for a random amount of time, because it suddenly stops working for a while.
I do not know how to make the News & Interests widget consistently animate, but I have made a discovery as to where to locate some of them from this Twitter post: https://x.com/StartIsBack/status/1794313299552817639, https://assets.msn.com/weathermapdata/1/static/weather/taskbar/animation/20240514.1.flight/Weather/W04_PartlyCloudy/W04_PartlyCloudy_01.svg for the newer one, and https://assets.msn.com/weathermapdata/1/static/weather/taskbar/animation/20240402.1/Weather/W04_PartlyCloudy/W04_PartlyCloudy_01.svg for the older one.
Changing the name to match the name of the frame finds them, but I want to know how to retrieve this URL from the icons shown on the News & Interests widget, to locate more of them.
Is this possible? Is there any way to locate the URL attached to displayed SVG files in that widget?
